# How to find what object is bound to a winform text box

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a textbox and an object is bound to the text. In code I need to find which object was bound.

I'm using a Windows.Forms.TextBox I have the DataBinding-Text bound to any objects name field. This is done at design time. In code I need to figure out what the object is that is bound to this TextBox.

Comment: provide sample code for your question

Comment: There is no code sample that is what I'm asking for. The editvalue would be set at design time.

Comment: Do you mean the bounded property of the object?

Comment: are you using some third party textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Try querying the textbox's [DataBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx) property at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In your code at runtime, assuming your bound object is some MyObject:

```
if (textBox1.DataBindings.Count == 1)
{
   var myObj = textBox1.DataBindings[0].DataSource as MyObject;

   if (myObj != null)
      // do something with the bound object
   else
      // well, found data bound object but it was not a MyObject... Handle as appropriate
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not return the object that is databound.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody still needs to know this: `textBox1.DataBindings("Text").BindingMemberInfo.BindingField` 
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Is the object stored in the tag of the Textbox?

```
object o = textbox.Tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the `DataBindings` of the textbox. The `DataSource` of the `Binding` can contain different things:

- A `Type` object describing the type of object the property can bind to. This can be the case when the form is loading and no object has been attached yet.
- A `BindingSource`. In this case, we must query the `DataSource` of this binding source.
- A data object or `null`.

In case we have a `BindingSource`, we can again have a `Type` object. To get the object type a binding is supposed to bind to, I wrote this helper method which calls itself recursively. *(using C#7.0 syntax)*

```
private Type GetBoundType(object dataSource)
{
    switch (dataSource) {
        case Type type:
            return type;
        case BindingSource bindingSource:
            return GetBoundType(bindingSource.DataSource);
        default:
            return dataSource?.GetType();
    }
}
```

You can call it like this *(using C#7.0 syntax)*:

```
Binding binding = textBox.DataBindings["Text"];
if (binding != null && GetBoundType(binding.DataSource) == expectedType) {
    ...
}
```

---

If you know that an actual data object has been bound to the data source you can get it with:

```
object entity = binding.DataSource is BindingSource bs ? bs.DataSource : binding.DataSource;
```